# Synchronization issue when running Protractor tests on an app with AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, protractor, angularfire

When writing tests in Protractor for an Angular2 app that's using AngularFire.

I am using `browser.ignoreSynchronization` as a workaround, otherwise my tests would timeout at each `it`. This forces me to write a lot of bloat code.

Is there a way to not be "forced" to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization`?

There are some discussions about this issue out there ([like this one](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/225)), but I don't see any definite solution. Does one exist at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the issue is still not solved perfectly.

May be instead of using the `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;` then and there, i would suggest you to use in the conf.js and  `browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;` at the teardown of each test suite.

That may reduce the so many bloat codes. 
Thanks.